# How to manually add the collection to the firebase realtime database correctly?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a collection called users on firebase.google.com, in this collection there are three documents, each document has three keys, nickname, age and fab and their corresponding values.

[image]

Please see the above image, if importing a json file, what is the format of the json file?
And if add the collection manually, what is the format?

I tried to uploaded a json file, but it doesn't work.

Updated: My mistake, I chose wrong, I should use Firestore Database.

Comment: The format of the JSON is going to match the structure of the data you're trying to add.  We can't really tell what exactly you're trying to add, though.  Please edit the question to show more clearly what you're trying to achieve (show clear examples), and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect (the JSON you're using that doesn't work the way you expect).

Comment: My mistake, I chose wrong, I should use Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a JSON you can import into Firebase of the format you describe:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "nickname": "user22144856",
      "age": 42,
      "fab": false
    },
    "user2": {
      "nickname": "codingdoug",
      "age": 42,
      "fab": true
    },
    "user3": {
      "nickname": "puf",
      "age": 42,
      "fab": true
    },
  }
}
```

If you save this to a file, you can import that file to any path in the database (including the root) and it will create the structure under it.

You can also copy the JSON from above, and paste it into the `Value` field in the Firebase console to get the same result.